# Angular Component not render html when add constructor

Tags: angular, http

In one of my components I display data that I get from a service I created, which uses http to get a data from external website through api.

Before adding the service, the components worked well (the component only displayed static html). Now, in order to use the service I need to inject the service to the component, so once I inject it to the constructor, it's no longer displays the static html, as well as - and this is really wired - also the router doesn't work. It will not route to this component and in the address bar will show the link of the latest component (latest link that was visiting)

Here's the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataDisplayFromAPI } from '../data-display-from-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-view',
  templateUrl: './main-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-view.component.css']
})

export class MainViewComponent implements OnInit {

objectKeys = Object.keys;
cryptos: any;

constructor (private coinsRateCryptoCompare: DataDisplayFromAPI) {}

title = 'Digital Coin Hub';

ngOnInit () {
    this.coinsRateCryptoCompare.getPrices()
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.cryptos = res;
        });
}

}
```

Now, if I only take out the private parameter from the component **private coinsRateCryptoCompare: DataDisplayFromAPI** the component shows the static html correct again:

```
constructor () {}

title = 'Digital Coin Hub';

ngOnInit () {
    //this.coinsRateCryptoCompare.getPrices()
        //.subscribe(res => {
        //  this.cryptos = res;
    //  });
}

}
```

But then obviously I can't use the http data

What's the problem?

Per the comments, this is the app module and the service.

The service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class DataDisplayFromAPI {

   result:any;

   constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

   getPrices() {
      return this._http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,IOT&tsyms=USD")
       .map(result => this.result = result);
   }
 }
```

The app module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; // import the     HTTP library to make our API calls

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { DigitalCoinHubService } from './digital-coin-hub.service';
import { DataDisplayFromAPI } from './data-display-from-api.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainViewComponent } from './main-view/main-view.component';
import { BuySellBitcoinComponent } from './buy-sell/buy-sell.component';
import { DigitalWalletComponent } from './digital-wallet/digital-   wallet.component';
import { JobsComponent } from './jobs/jobs.component';
import { DigitalCoinsComponent } from './digital-coins/digital-   coins.component';
import { MiningComponent } from './mining/mining.component';
import { StartupsComponent } from './startups/startups.component';
import { EthereumComponent } from './ethereum/ethereum.component';
import { NewsComponent } from './news/news.component';
import { BuyWithDigitalCoinComponent } from './buy-with/buy-   with.component';
import { BannerWideComponent } from './banner-wide/banner-  wide.component';

 @NgModule({
     declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     MainViewComponent,
     BuySellBitcoinComponent, 
     DigitalWalletComponent,
     JobsComponent,
     DigitalCoinsComponent,
     MiningComponent,
     StartupsComponent,
     EthereumComponent,
     NewsComponent, 
     BuyWithDigitalCoinComponent, 
     BannerWideComponent
   ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
 ],
providers: [DigitalCoinHubService, DataDisplayFromAPI],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Are there errors in the console? It looks like your service causes a runtime error during its initialization phase.

Comment: Try taking '.service' out of  '../data-display-from-api.service'. I believe you aren't supposed to put the file extension when adding components, services, etc.

Comment: It would be easier to debug the issue if you show us the `DataDisplayFromAPI` service's source code.

Comment: @BrandonMiller I have other services in this website and always using the .service extension. I think also in the angular documentation this what they do. Anyway, it's works fine with the .service as long as I take out the parameter from the constructor. The thing that causes the problem is the parameter in the constructor: private coinsRateCryptoCompare: DataDisplayFromAPI once I take it out it's works fine. (But then I need to remove obviously the code inside ngOnInit () as I did in my question above

Comment: Can you share your console and your app.module file?

Comment: Ok, I added to the question the module and the service

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for the help. Problem solved. I added HttpClientModule in the imports and now it works. So apparently this was the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I added **HttpClientModule** to the @NgModule imports and it solved the problem:

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
HttpClientModule,
```

Thanks for your help. Problem solved.